# Impedance matching on RP2040

Tags: usb-c

I really like your RP2040 chip and am using this to design a new small footprint PCB that offers USB and Ethernet access.  The problem I am encountering is understanding your USB specs.

Here on page 11, the first two paragraphs:
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf

You mention the need for impedance matching the USB lines.  I am not new to this concept and indeed if I use the numbers you provide for the traces, i.e. 1mm thickness FR4, 0.8mm track and separation of 0.15mm, we get ~90 impedance.  That's all good, so why do I then need the 27ohm series resistors as this will make the total impedance ~143ohm differentially.  This really does not make sense to me! I am happy to just implement it but it would be good to understand why when the traces meet the USB spec, you are adding additional resistors?

Comment: Understand this one thing: The RP2040 is not ***our*** chip. It is made the the Raspberry Pi Foundation, and their partners. ***We** are StackExchange - a Question and Answer site.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have confused **Impedance matching** and **Resistance matching**? You simply cannot add up resistances and arrive at an [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance).

Wrt your question, all I can offer is this: Unless you have prior experience with design and layouts for USB interfaces, I would *suggest* you go with the recommendations.